# Replicating Dev database to QA database using SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloning, database-cloning

I have a Dev database and I want to create a new schema called QA database which should  be a replica (in all aspects including stages) of Dev database.

Could someone please let me know how this can be done in SNOWFLAKE?

Comment: Are these both in the same account?  If so, use `CLONE`.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Comment: You mixed up database and schemas little bit but try `CREATE DATABASE QA CLONE DEV`